# Deleberate Malware Insertion

Tags: testing, malware

This question made me sit and think for a while. I was wondering why deliberately inserting malware into code you are developing is not an example of negligence. It's a test process isn't it? I'm sure when developing anti-malware software, they need some sort of testing process to see how well his/her/their software copes with the real malware. And when developing a software, don't developers or testers attempt to break and exploit software to see its weakness, and how well it performs, to evaluate its capability, attribution, and etc?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is it depends on how you define malware. If you define it by the attacker's (malicious) intention then you would never be inserting malware into your code if it is for testing reasons. You would be making it more secure instead.

Comment: I can't still comment on other user's questions yet, but why should it be a comment?

Answer (score 0):

As someone who works for an antivirus company: We do not develop malware to test the antivirus product. That is not necessary and doing so is seen as bad practice in the field.

That does not mean that we do not have test files, but the ones we create ourselves are not malicious. A program is only malicious if it causes some form of damage (financially, psychologically, systemic or physical damage). But apart from that malware is not much different from legitimate programs. So if you test certain aspects of an antivirus product, you can create clean programs that just have a specific characteristic which is shared by certain malware, but without causing damage.

Apart from that we use the malware that is already abundandly there to test if detection technologies and signatures work as expected.